# How to check if mail is sent successfully or canceled?

Tags: c#, outlook

I create an Outlook mail like this:

```
 Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
 mailItem.Subject = mailSubject;
 mailItem.To = "";
 mailItem.Attachments.Add(totalPath);
 mailItem.Body = mailBody;
 mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
 mailItem.Display(true);
 //Mail is send succesfully?
```

Is it possible to check if the mail is sent successfully or canceled?

When I execute the following code, the error appears

> 'the item is moved or deleted'

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Subject = mailSubject;
mailItem.To = "";
mailItem.CC = "EDI.Orders@trust.com";
mailItem.Attachments.Add(totalPath);
mailItem.Body = mailBody;
mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
mailItem.Display(true);
//Mail is send succesfully?
if (mailItem.Sent)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Sended");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("canceled");
}
```

The error appears at `mailItem.Sent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mailItem.Sent` property shows if the E-Mail has been sent.

Additionally you can attach to the `mailItem.Write` event. (But take care - will also get called on just saving & so on)

```
mailItem.Write += mailItem_Write;

void mailItem_Write(ref bool Cancel)
    {
       //your code...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`MailItem.Sent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868242.aspx) property returns a Boolean value that indicates if a message has been sent.

Comment: When i use the MaiItem.Sent the error appears "The item is moved or deleted"

Answer (score 1):

For your question;

> MailItem.Sent Property (Outlook)
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates if a message has been sent.
>   Read-only.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868242.aspx

When checking this property after Display has been called, I suspect that as the item is no longer Active, the call to `Sent` is failing. One way you could potentially confirm if the mail has indeed been Sent is by handling the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx) event of the Outlook.Application class.

```
        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

        outlookApp.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(outlookApp_ItemSend);

        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = "Test";
        mailItem.To = "a.b@c.com";
        mailItem.CC = "";

        mailItem.Body = "Test Message";
        mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
        mailItem.Display(true);
```

And in the Send event handler check the message;

```
void outlookApp_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
    {
        string subject = ((Outlook.MailItem)Item).Subject;


        if (subject == "Test")
        {
            //Item sent
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will not block outlook.

```
class Class1
{
    static bool mailWasSent = false;
    private static System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext _context;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
        mailItem.Subject = "My Subject";
        mailItem.To = "";
        mailItem.Attachments.Add(@"C:\test.pdf");
        mailItem.Body = "This is my Body-Text";
        mailItem.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
        ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Close += MailItem_onClose;
        ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mailItem).Send += MailItem_onSend;

        //mailItem.Display(true);   // This call will make mailItem MODAL - 
        // This way, you are not allowed to create another new mail, ob browse Outlook-Folders while mailItem is visible

        // Using ApplicationContext will wait until your email is sent or closed without blocking other Outlook actions.
        using (_context = new System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext())
        {
            mailItem.Display();
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(_context);     
        }
        if (mailWasSent)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Email was sent");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Email was NOT sent");
        }
    }

    private static void MailItem_onSend(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        mailWasSent = true;
    }

    private static void MailItem_onClose(ref bool Cancel)
    {
        _context.ExitThread();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task and none of the suggestions above cover all cases. Some are outright wrong.

We know that Outlook.MailItem in C# is a mere RCW (Runtime Callable Wrapper) which is very loosely coupled with the COM object, so when the object is gone it will throw COMException "The item is moved...".

When we create Outlook.MailItem in C# the only unique identifier is the reference to the RCW (no EntryID, no whatever other ID on the COM object - NONE!). When the code calls Display() on the object it is a non blocking call the RCW reference will be lost if not assigned upon exit from the calling routine. Display(true) will block.
There are also 2 Send events to hook up to: one on the MailItem itself and another on the Application as suggested in the earlier posts. The one on MailItem is raised first and then followed by Application's event. Since there is no default item ID on the MailItem object it can only identified by some secondary custom properties. Note that RCW of the Item in Application.Send event handler is different and not equal to the original MailItem RCW.

Problem solved?
Not quite! Due to the parasite apps (SendGuard etc.) which feast on the same event.

There is a chance that user will revert sending by responding to the prompts of the parasite apps which will result any suggestions incorrectly marking the item as sent. The solution in this case is probably attaching and handling Close event of the Outlook.MailItem. Booth the problem and the feature here is that if the e-mail is sent the reference to the COM object Outlook.MailItem will be gone. RCW will throw exception when trying to access any property of it in Close handler. This is understandable, because Microsoft is protecting stability of their app and is removing reference to COM object upon successfully completing send. The wrong here is that Cancelled parameter in the handler will not have any effect in this case. If the user simply decides to Close Outlook.MailItem the RCW in Close handler will have the reference to the Outlook.MailItem and Cancelled will prevent close if set to True in the handler.

To confuse more, the user may Save the Outlook.MailItem for later sending and close it. If there is no reference to RCW the object will no longer be accessible. If the reference is maintained in the program, whenever user reopens saved draft it will handle the events normally. To capture that you may use Inspector.Close and Outlook.MailItem.Write events.

So what worked for me was:

- Maintain RCW to the created MailItem object in the program.
- Attach Send, Write and Close events handlers to MailItem.
- Attach Close event handler to the Inspector to capture if the modified e-mail has been saved for later sending
- Make Sent/Not Send decision and dereferencing of RCW (and COM object if user closed e-mail) in Close handlers of the MailItem (Sent) and Inspector
  (Not saved.)

Comment: That is not true. "The item is moved..." exception is raised by the Outlook Object Model, not the RCW wrapper. As soon as a message is submitted (either by clicking the Send item or calling MailItem.Send), it is owned by the spooler and the only valid operation i releasing a reference to that object. The spooler moves the message to the Outbox folder (by creating a new object there and deleting the original item). If the message was sent successfully, it then moved (delete+create) to the Sent Items folder. It is a physically different message. The original one is gone.

Comment: The moral of the story is that you should not hold a reference to an item that can be sent. Your first chance to access the sent item is when Items.ItemAdd event fires on the Sent Items folder.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I absolutely agree with your description of the sent mail lifecycle flow. It still has a flaw. Outlook has a setting to not save the sent e-mail. After few rounds of UAT I discovered a fringe case: user saves the e-mail and then deletes it via the Outlook interface (no Inspector open) or closes Outlook (remove all references) in the first case I end up with dead reference to the RCW. I took that as bearable evil and clean it up when user ends the section in program.

Comment: Agreed - but the reference is dead NOT from the RCW point of view (it is still a perfectly good IMailItem interface), but from the OOM point of view. It simply returns a COM exception from every method you call on that interface. It will returns the same error even if RCW is not involved at all - e.g., from an unmanaged COM addin written in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Outlook only gives you a loosely coupled reference,

```
            Outlook.MailItem eMail = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

As soon as you've executed eMail.Display(true) you can no longer use the eMail object, this is because Outlook has moved the email to the 'outbox'

I have a Boolean called 'display' which is true if the caller wants to display the email to the user. If false the Send() method can be called without problems.

Please note that if the user has Outlook running there's no need to call the 'send' method, once it's in the 'outbox' Outlook will pick it up and send it.  The rest of the code only has to deal with the case of the user not having Outlook open.

But if true I get a new reference to Outlook, and check whether 'outbox' contains items, and whether it contains more items than before. The user might not have pressed 'send', he/she might have closed the email without saving it.  I ran into a permissions error when trying to send the email, so made a copy, sent that, and deleted the original from the 'outbox' and then also deleted it from the bin.

```
            if (display)
            {
                eMail.Display(true);  //true = modal (a pop-up window).  True makes it a blocking call, but after the email has been displayed the 'eMail' object can no longer be used
                                      //if calling Display(false) the email flashes briefly on the screen, and the .Send() method executes without error, but it doesn't send, it just leaves the email in Outbox.
            }
            else
            {
                eMail.Send();
            }
            oNS.Logoff();

            if (display)
            {  
                Boolean success = false;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        oApp = new Outlook.Application(); //this fails if Outlook is running a background process (disposing of the email window resources)
                        success = true;
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                }
                while (!success);
                oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");
                success = false;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        outlookAlreadyOpen = oNS.CurrentProfileName?.Length != null; //it's a way to check whether Outlook application is open
                        success = true;
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(10);
                    }
                }
                while (!success);
                
                if (!outlookAlreadyOpen) //if it's open Outlook will send the email and move it from 'outbox' to 'sent items'
                {
                    //if Outlook is not open we need to send it outselves, otherwise it stays in the 'outbox'
                    oNS.Logon(contractsDatabase.properties.emailProfile, Missing.Value, true, true);

                    outboxFolder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderOutbox);

                    if (outboxFolder.Items.Count > 0 && outboxFolder.Items.Count > countOutboxFolder)
                    {
                        eMail = outboxFolder.Items.GetLast(); //last is the most recent, i.e. the email that the user pressed 'send'.
                        eMail.Copy().Send(); //we don't have permission to send the original email, so send a copy instead
                        MAPIFolder deletedItemsFolder = oApp.Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDeletedItems);
                        int countDeletedItemsFolder = deletedItemsFolder.Items.Count;
                        eMail.Delete();
                        if (deletedItemsFolder.Items.Count > 0 && deletedItemsFolder.Items.Count > countDeletedItemsFolder)
                        {
                            //first check that an item came to deleted items, because outlook could be set set to not move emails to deleted items folder according to user preferences
                            deletedItemsFolder.Items.GetLast().Delete();
                        }
                    }

                    oNS.Logoff();
                }
            }
```